# OS X syslog ignores setlogmask and only logs errors

Tags: c++, cocoa, logging, osx-yosemite, syslog

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, writing a Cocoa application in C++

I'm trying to set the logging level for syslog using setlogmask, but it seems to only log error messages.  Code:

```
openlog("test", ( LOG_CONS | LOG_PID), LOG_USER );
setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));
syslog(LOG_ERR, "abcdefg error log.");
syslog(LOG_INFO, "abcdefg info log.");
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "abcdefg debug log.");
```

Only the error log shows in /var/log/system.log
Just in case I was misunderstanding the LOG_UPTO I've tried

```
setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));
setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_ERR));
setlogmask(0);
setlogmask(255);
```

Always getting the same result:

```
Feb 16 12:47:53 Mac-Pro.local test[28408]: abcdefg error log.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  The /etc/asl.conf sets the syslog to ignore anything below warning, which makes sense.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/asl.conf.5.html